# How to lock effectively for normal variable with multi-thread program C in linux

Tags: c, linux, mutex, memory-barriers

I program C inLinux. Normally, we can use `mutex` to lock & unlock a normal variable (eg `int`, `bool`...) in multi-thread program. But i read some information `mutex` be not effectively. Someone recommend use `memory barrier` instead of `volatile`.

Can you example use `memory-barrier` effectively and exactly for normal variable in multi-thread program, with bool variable is exchange true/false.

Thank for your support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mutexes are perfectly fine at locking access (assuming it's a legitimate mutex, used properly, not some home-rolled piece of garbage). It might not be the most efficient, but it's effective.

Memory barriers are typically *not* sufficient, and should rarely be coded explicitly (instead, you'd use C11's `stdatomic.h` with appropriate memory ordering and let the compiler handle inserting barriers as needed). But atomics are a microoptimization you really shouldn't be getting into when you're clearly new to threading. Stick to simple mutexes until you find a *need* for more fine-grained control/speed.

`volatile` is generally garbage too; it's a poor sop for true atomics that didn't work consistently across compilers and architectures, but got abused before there was good support for atomics in the hope it would help. It had all sorts of pitfalls, while offering little and costing a lot. `volatile` should be the last thing you consider when it comes to synchronizing data across threads; it's for DMA hardware, don't abuse it for other purposes.

Comment: I feel hard to decide because Linus don't use C11. So tha,t I think about use memory barries. And i used mutex for our program, now i want improve speed. Thank you.

Comment: @TrungTrinh: "Linux don't use C11" - That does not make sense. glibc should be C11 compliant mostly on a recent distribution and gcc also supports C11 since 4.7 (4.9 with full atomics support, before that there were mostly compatible work-arounds via an external header).

Comment: @TrungTrinh: The Linux kernel uses C89, because it's a large legacy code base where upgrading risks all sorts of compatibility issues. That is not a reason that all code everywhere should be C89. It's been 28 years; there have been meaningful improvements. `gcc` *defaults* to C11 at this point, reinventing your own threading/synchronization constructs from poorly suited primitives like memory barriers should not be your concern at this point.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Thank you :)